# jQuery: target third class using jquery .closest?

Tags: jquery

I am validating the 3rd up `.member_owned_100` class. right now its targeting the last/closet only. i have tried `.closest` but no luck.

```
 $(".member_owned_100").match("number").sum(100);
```

Comment: Show `html` and relevant `js` code

Comment: sorry... I don't think it is clear... can you share the html sample and tell what you are looking for

Comment: A fiddle'd be helpful.

Comment: do you want the 3th parent of this class?

Comment: @acctman - Please response you only post the question right. All are have work Otherwise your question be unclear

Comment: @JqueryKing I want the 3rd .member_owned_100 class ... when I use .closest it gives me the last showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the *3rd* div with class `.member_owned_100`, you can do it with:

```
// .eq() selects by index
$(".member_owned_100").eq(2);
```

Or:

```
// jQuery uses css type selectors too
$(".member_owned_100:nth-child(3)").match("number").sum(100);
```

If you want to get the 3rd parent you can do it with `.parents()` and `.eq()`:

```
// gets the 3rd element parent
$(".member_owned_100").parents().eq(2);
```

If you want to get the 3rd parent *with same class* you can do it with `.parents()` and `.eq()` too:

```
// gets the 3rd element parent with same class
$(".member_owned_100").parents(".member_owned_100").eq(2);
```

Else if you are looking for another solution I'll edit this post (if I can help you) when you update your question with more information.

Answer (score 1):

I think he wants the third class up the dom from a particular element.  If that is the case you will want to use [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) and select the third item:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="member_owned_100">
         <div class="member_owned_100">
            <div class="member_owned_100">
               <div class="member_owned_100">
                  <span id="starting-element"></span>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>


$('#starting-element').parents('.member_owned_100').eq(2);
```